# ASP.net How make an element on the Navigation Bar disappear through calling an if statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call an action after an if statement where the element on the navigation bar disappears.

So for example, I want the element that says "Upload File" disappeared after I start after calling the first part of the if statement

Note: I'm calling the if statement in the _Layout.cshtml where the element was created. I would like to know if this is the correct place where I'm calling it.

**If statement**

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Member"))
{

}
```

**Element**

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Upload File", "UploadFile", "Home")</li>
```

"Member" in the if statement is coming from the `ASPNetRoles` in the local database which works perfectly fine.

Comment: Done. Posted an edit.

Comment: This would make the whole navbar vanish...

Comment: What do you mean _disappear after I start after calling the first part of the if statement_? What are you expecting to happen and what currently happens (you question makes no sense)

Comment: You are trying to use 'if' statement and the issue you facing is probably that your fileupload control hides itself upon using 'if'. Am I right?

Comment: I have set up the registration form where you can either register as a "File Owner" or "Member" by creating two radio buttons and whatever radio button they select the database table , so for example; I register an account by selecting the "member" radio button and in my local database in the 'ASPNetUserRoles' table it assigns the user id and the role id of which radio button the user registered as. "Member" & "FileOwner" are assigned to a role ID in the 'ASPNetRoles' 

What I'm trying to do is that only the "FileOwner" to have access to the "Upload file" element and disappears for other roles

Comment: Then add a property to your view model (or to `ViewBag`) - (say) `bool canUploadFile` which you assign in the GET method and then `@if(Model.canUpload){ // render the html for the link }`